For what values of $k$ does the double integral of $\frac{1}{\|x_A - x_B\|^k}$ over intersecting surfaces converge?
I am working on a problem related to defining a potential energy function based on the distance between two intersecting surfaces in Euclidean space. Specifically, I am considering the following potential energy function:
$$\phi(d) = \frac{1}{d^k}$$
where $d$ is the distance between points on the two surfaces $A$ and $B$.
The total energy $E$ is given by the double integral:
$$E = \int_A \int_B \frac{1}{\|x_A - x_B\|^k} dA dB$$
I need to determine for what values of $k$ this integral converges when the two surfaces intersect.
To restate more clearly:

Two regular surfaces $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ may intersect.
I am interested in the convergence of the integral when $x_A \in A$ and $x_B \in B$ approach each other, i.e., when the surfaces intersect.

Could someone help me determine the conditions on $k$ that ensure the convergence of this integral? Many thanks in advance!
